# Phone app with nexmo voice app integration

Tags: webrtc, vonage, webrtc-android, voice-interaction

I am mobile app developer. I have a Phone app with nexmo sdk in-app voice integration.

Whats the procedure to work on it.

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario, `from` will be your phone number (from which you're doing call forwarding), and not your customer 123*** phone number https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/guides/call-flow#answer-url-payload

I suggest you have the customer call the Nexmo virtual number instead, do your validation and then `connect` or `transfer` the call to your acctual phone number via the Nexmo NCCO.

Here's the documentation for transfering a call, if your validation takes longer and you need to put the person calling on hold in the meantime: https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/code-snippets/transfer-a-call

If your validation is faster, here's how to connect an inbound call to a different number: https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/code-snippets/connect-an-inbound-call